# Getting information from a text box - Full Tilt Poker

Tags: user-interface, textbox, poker

Full Tilt Poker's GUI has a box of text that keeps reporting on the state the current hand. I wanted to be able to parse that text but do not know how to gain access to it, so if anyone could point me in the proper direction, I would appreciate it greatly.

Image with the GUI and text box: http://img143.imageshack.us/img143/6660/ftpbox.jpg .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [neat analysis of harvesting data from an online Poker GUI interface](http://www.codingthewheel.com/archives/how-i-built-a-working-poker-bot) is a pretty nice read; they suggest, for accessing the text, API Hooking with something like [detour](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/).

They also suggest the much-more-painless method of reading the actual log/hand history output that most poker clients write to the disk in real-time.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot! It seems VERY VERY helpful; I'll look at it after work. I know about the hand histories, but I am trying to look into the usefulness of having the current state of the hand (only stuff that FTP would allow). The problem with hand histories is that they do not show up until after the hand is over. But once again, thanks!

Comment: No problem; the site mentions that some poker services do actually publish Hand Histories or Logs in real time.  Have you tried checking for more general logs in Full Tilt?